# Access Token for facebook insights graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-insights

I have looked through many questions and answers but I cannot find out why I can't get insights working it always returns a paginated response which says that the request requires an access token. I used the graph explorer to go to an app and requested all extended permissions including read_insights then got the access token. I extended the app's access token so it never expired. I used that token to make an insights request for a page with no luck. So I tried to obtain the page's access token but that didn't work either can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

dude, if you're trying to access insights for a page whom you're not admin then you won't get much data (only public data for it).

Please mention your problem more clearly also.